# excel averaging every nth row and column blocks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big data set which has more than 100k rows and 191 columns. i need to calculate every tenth row for all the columns.
my data looks something like this:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 | 9 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 | 9 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 | 9 | 8 |

how can i calculate the average for every nth row in excel

Comment: Then where result will be shown? What is your excel version.

Comment: next to the top right cell. My original values has GI as last column so GJ 63 (next to my first line of actula values)

Comment: Could you add an example of expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an aside 100k rows, 191 columns.  a very large data set but probably still alittle surprised at 1.5gb.

depends where you want the averages but lets assume you want them in another cell B2 of another sheet and just an average in each row and that your current sheet is called Data:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Data!$A$1,(ROW(B2)-2)*10,0,10,191))
```

this is an average of all the columns

by the way unless you have a beast of a machine your computer will hate this!  and I would suggest using VBA rather than this but it should work

Answer (score 1):

With latest update of ***Microsoft 365*** can try-

```
=BYROW(FILTER(A1:E24,MOD(ROW(A1:A24),10)=0),LAMBDA(a,AVERAGE(a)))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want overall average of every 10th row then try `=AVERAGE(FILTER(A1:E24,MOD(ROW(A1:A24),10)=0))`.

Comment: thank you but i dont use the microsoft 365 version because my data is 1.5 gb

Comment: so two things, it doesn't have to be online to use this function (have just tried it in my desktop version).  though I haven't done anything with these functions but just copying it into excel didnt seem to give me the right answers on my mock up